# Update existing PowerPoint graphs using R?

Tags: r, powerpoint, reporters

I know it is easy to [update existing slides using ReporteRs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28285380/r-reporters-editing-existing-slides), however I am interested in editing the data in a number of templated graphs within an existing PowerPoint file. To be clear, my PPTX has a number of animated graphs (i.e. not images), which I usually copy/paste data into (which comes from R, as a .csv), I would like for R to directly insert that data into the PowerPoint.

One limitation is that the graphs are embedded in the PPTX, so I cannot simply edit an existing excel file which that PPTX can use to populate the plots. I could in theory have one document that the graphs take data from, and update that via R, but the location of that file changes (template that is copied to new locations for each new project), which breaks all the links in the PPTX and having to edit 50+ links is tedious.

Comment: If reproducibility is the goal, it would be a lot simpler to use one of [the RMarkdown slide formats](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/formats.html) instead of PowerPoint. Obviously porting is not fun, but if it's something you'll use freqently it may be worth it to be able to reknit with a single click or call.

Comment: That's not a feature of `ReporteRs`. Unfortunately, this would require lot of time to be implemented.